Kid's dog chewing on device that looks like a bone, turns out to be a bomb
So this was a Sci-Fi TV series about a kid who happens to find part of a device that looked like a bone that his dog was chewing. This device was later known to be a bomb. The boy was joined by some crazy professor to find the rest of the parts of this device so that the villain won't be able to get them first. They travelled through vast dimensions to collect the remaining parts of the device. Also, it has a crazy plot twist at the end of the series, the villain turned out to be a good guy who actually created the device and then wanted to keep it away from evil (I know its weird creating device that can destroy whole world, then try to keep it out of evil hands), and professor wanted to get the device to rule the world.
More details:

It's live action.
It came out before 2007
It targeted teenage audience
Show didn't take itself too seriously since they travelled through very silly dimensions.


Year (approximation)? Western? Asian? More information could be useful.

Animated? Live action?

I edited my question for more information.

possible duplicate of Looking for the name of a children's Sci-fi film series in the late 90s to early 2000s

This sounds like it would be an appropriate "Eerie Indiana" plot, or its sequel series, but I haven't seen them in years.

Bob, if you're still around, I think I found it (after some thorough brain-racking): Josh Kirby: Time Warrior from 1995-96. From the recap:

The series concerns a device, found by humans in the 25th century, called the Nullifier. This device is said to be capable of destroying the universe. Realising the danger, a man called Irwin 1138 splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are then dispersed through time. However, a scientist called Dr. Zoetrope finds out where the pieces are located and, with the help of his time traveling armor, sets about reassembling the device. Along with 20th-century teenager Josh Kirby, and a half-human warrior known as Azabeth Siege, Irwin 1138 sets about thwarting Dr. Zoetrope's plans.

It all fits: It starts after the boy finds a glass bone in his dog's kennel; they travel to different, sometimes silly worlds (like a toy world in one episode); and in the end, Dr. Zoetrope isn't evil after all, and Irwin betrays Josh. There were 6 chapters in all. Here's the trailer:



